# Filter an array of nested objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of nested objects and I have a user, which searches for a room
Here is an array of objects.

[image]

I would like to filter an array as soon as user types something

I tried a lot of functions, but nothing worked for me, here is the last example, which failed

```
search(val: any) {
// if input is clear - show everything, what we have

    if (val === '') {
      this.roomList = this.roomList;
    } else {
//choose the object (objects) where rName = val

      this.roomList = this.roomList.staticData.rName.filter(function(o) {
        return Object.keys(o).some(function(k) {
          return o[k].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) != -1;
        })
      });
    }
  }
```

Could you please help or give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `Array.filter()` on `roomList` instead of `staticData` propety

```
this.roomList = this.roomList.filter(function (r) {
    return r.staticData.rName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) != -1
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.roomList = this.roomList.staticData.rName
```

This is a wrong starting point, just look at it. Then, `rName` is not an array, so you can't invoke `.filter` on it.

Here's how to do it :

```
this.roomListFiltered = this.roomList.filter(o => new RegExp(val,"i").test(o.staticData.rName) )
```

`new RegExp(val,"i")` performs a case-insensitive match.

Also, store the result of the filter in a different variable, otherwise you will lose your original list as it gets filtered out.

Comment: Because unfortunately that's common place on SO. Make a correct answer and get a few silent downvotes for some reason. Here, that could have been because OP uses ES5, not ES6, but I wouldn't have been told by the downvoter.